# C# VS2019 - Implement Multiple pages in one form that switch with a click of a button

Tags: c#

I've tried many methods to try and get this to work, but have had very little success making it stable. What would be a good way of going about this? 
When I click the first button I can view my first panel just fine, but it permanently hides the second panel despite me click button 2 which in theory should unhide the first panel and and show the second one. I'm guessing this method is outdated. I should note that both panels are directly on top of each other. If anyone has a solution to this please let me know.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstPanel.Show();
        secondPanel.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondPanel.Show();
        firstPanel.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you have one panel _inside_ the other one, not just on top of each other. Consider using a [`TabControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol) instead. You can have multiple pages displayed as tabs or you can hide the tab headers and switch tabs programmatically using button clicks.

Comment: You can figure out if the two panels are siblings (i.e., what you think they are) or if one panel contains the other by looking at the `FormName.designer.cs` file (don't make any changes there unless you *really* know what you are doing).  But, it's good to poke around and see how things work

Comment: Thanks, I used UserControls.